# Dynamically allocated char array shows as uninitialized with constructor

Tags: c++

When compiling this code, I get this warning:

> Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialized value(s)

My set function is using a dynamic array and I wish to have it delete the dynamic space if it already exists.

The class:

```
class Name
{
    char* m_name;

public:
    Name();
    Name(const char*);
    ~Name();
    void set(const char*);
}
```

The constructor and setEmpty():

```
void Name::setEmpty()
{
    m_name = nullptr;
}
```

```
Name::Name()
{
    setEmpty();
}
```

The function:

```
void Name::set(const char* name)
{
    if (name == nullptr || std::strlen(name) == 0)
    {
        setEmpty(); // <-- What my constructor has; sets 'm_name' to nullptr;
    }
    else
    {
        int length = std::strlen(name) + 1;
        if (m_name != nullptr) // <-- gives warning because m_name is not initialized however it was created via constructor (?)
        {
        delete[] m_name;
        }
        m_name = new char[length]; // <-- No matter what I want to re-create the dynamic array
        std::strcpy(m_name, name);
    }
}
```

Main():

```
int main()
{
    // constructors
    Name s1("Sample");
    Name s2, s3;
    Name badData[] = {
        Name ("Kappa"),
        Name("Omega"),
        Name(nullptr),
        Name("", )
    };
    s1.set("Sample");

//...//
}
```

Comment: The c tag is inappropriate here. This is c++. c does not have classes.

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Please read about and provide a [MCVE].

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux yes. I was just doing it to simplify the code visually. I can add the class name back.

Comment: this misunderstanding happens sometimes, fact is: you do not make your code more readable or simpler to understand by artifically introducing errors or leaving out parts of it. Please read about [mcve]

Comment: @idclev463035818 Amended. Thanks!

Comment: Btw `delete` on `nullptr` is a noop and it is guaranteed by C++ standard. So simply delete the pointer

Comment: well this is still not a mcve as far as I can tell, but I dont know how to help other than reminding you of the same link again: [mcve]. Details do matter! A missing `;` can make the difference between working code and a wall of errors that are hard to decipher

Comment: It's not terribly clear, but if your class has any constructors that don't call `setEmpty()`,  possibly one of them does not initialise `m_name`.   If that happens, a subsequent call of `set()` with a non-null pointer for which `strlen()` returns a non-zero value will test the value of `m_name` when it is uninitialised.   You haven't shown how the constructor that accepts a `const char *` is defined, so it is possible that constructor is the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's not terribly clear, but if your class has any constructors that don't call setEmpty(), possibly one of them does not initialise m_name. If that happens, a subsequent call of set() with a non-null pointer for which strlen() returns a non-zero value will test the value of m_name when it is uninitialised. You haven't shown how the constructor that accepts a const char * is defined, so it is possible that constructor is the culprit. – Peter 5 mins ago

This actually was the problem.

Solution:

```
Name::Name(const char* name)
    {
        setEmpty(); // <-- call safe state in all constructors
        set(name, dob, power, level, super);
    }
```

I didn't realize I needed to call either the function or the constructor that initializes values before I use my set function in the *overloaded* constructor.

Thank you Peter.